# We throw 6-side dice 5 times. Find probability that we will have exactly 4 different values.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am not sure if I did it correctly.

Of course
$|\Omega|=6^5$

Now $A=\{$event that we obtained exactly 4 different results on 5 throws$\}$

$$|A|= {{6}\choose{1}}{5\choose2}{5\choose1}{4\choose1}{3\choose1}$$

Which means that firstly we choose value which will occur twice. Next we choose on which throws it will occur. Afterwards we just choose 3 different values for remaining spots.

Comment: The no. of cases that we can have exactly 4 different results is: $5\choose4$.$6.5.4.3$. $4$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A favorable outcome is given by

- A duplicate number ($6$ choices) occurring at two different positions ($\binom{5}{2}$ choices);
- Two missing numbers different from the duplicate number ($\binom{5}{2}$ choices);
- A permutation of the three numbers that are not duplicate or missing ($6$ choices).

There are $6^5$ possibile outcomes, hence the wanted probability is
$$ \frac{6^2 \binom{5}{2}^2}{6^5} = \frac{100}{6^3} = \color{red}{\frac{25}{54}} \approx 46.3\%.$$

Comment: Well, that means that I was right. Although in less economical way.

Comment: Yes I got it wrong. So I deleted the thing. Kinda weird. Kinda messed it up big time. Really sorry.  But I'm not editing any more. Kinda too much confusion. Should've been more careful.

Comment: Your answer is correct. Again, my apologies for carelessness. Should've read the question more attentively, and should've checked my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference and to help with internet searches: using Stirling numbers of the second kind we get

$${6\choose 4}\times {5\brace 4} \times 4! \times \frac{1}{6^5}
= \frac{3600}{6^5} = \frac{25}{54}.$$